# CheckBox CheckedChanged Event without autopostback

Tags: c#, checkbox, asp.net-3.5

The CheckedChanged event of a checkbox fires upon autopostback. Is there a way to fire that event with autopostback set to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By a manual postback.
Seriously, how could an event fire without posting back?

Comment: I think the OP means that it should fire when the page is eventually posted, if the value has changed.

Comment: no, not eventually posted. It should fire when the user checks and unchecks the checkbox. I need to add javascript to make this happen.

Comment: The question is misleading then. Mentioning CheckedChanged event in a question tagged as asp.net leads me right to the server side. Good luck, anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to fire the event without telling the user that you have made a round trip to the server
you can fire the event by ajax

```xml
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb" oncheckedchanged="cb_CheckedChanged">
        </asp:CheckBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The OnCheckedChanged is a proprerty of `CheckBok object` (Control) in ASP.NET.

To fire the javascript code you have to use `OnClick="checkboxchanged(this);"` and check manually if the the value `checked` was changed:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb" onclick="checkboxchanged(this);" />

function checkboxchanged( sender ) {
    if ( sender.checked ) {
        // clicked and checked
    } else {
        // clicked and unchecked
    }
}
```